# download big EXCEL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis-express

I'm using WINDOWS 7,  IIS 7 Express
I want to download a excel .xlsx file（2013） from server. it can be downloaded but can't be opened.  The same problem when using xls. What do i miss?
Here is the code:

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";


        string mediaName = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["n"].ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaName))
        {
            return;
        }
        string destPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/EXCELtemplates/" + mediaName);
        // Check to see if file exist
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(destPath);

        try
        {
            if (fi.Exists)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fi.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
              //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";   // (xlsx)
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Has it been blocked by Security settings? Right click on the downloaded file and select properties, is the button "Unblock" enabled?

Comment: What is the error you got when you open the file?

Comment: The error is "There was a problem sending the command to the program."

Comment: @Alxwest I can't find "Unblock" button. The excel file properties looks normal

Comment: You only mentioned in the title that the file is big. How big is it? Why do you think the problem is related to the size of the document?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was the size problem. but now I change to the small excel file, only 11KB, it still gets error.

Comment: I published the code to the public server. and my friend have downloaded, and it's ok to open. It seems the problem is my office software.  Thanks for all your help.